# Update an entry in a MongoDB database only if it already exists

Tags: c#, mongodb

So I'm storing a log of users that join an IRC chat, keeping the time they logged in (and other stuff) and the time they log off, right now I'm adding a new entry every time that happens and whenever I need the info I just take it all and use Last() to get the latest one, I recognize this is inefficient since it'll only get slower as time passes and more users log in, so how can I update the last entry (so I don't have to remove everything and lose all I got until now) but, if that user hasn't joined before, create a new entry instead.

While at it, is there an efficient way to remove all entries except for the last one?

The programming language I'm using is C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findAndModify` http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#dbcmd.findAndModify to find an existing record and if it exists update the `LastLogin` or `LastLogoff` fields as appropriate.

If it doesn't exist you can go create it.

Since `findAndmodify` also supports a sort order you can even use this in the case where you do keep multiple records per user - findAndModify the most recent open login to close it. But unless you need an audit trail of every session I'd stick with a single user record, or if you did need an audit trail, do it in a separate collection and still maintain the last logon / logoff in the user record.

Comment: How can I tell whether findAndModify was executed or if I need to create a new record?

Comment: See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#findandmodify-value-field for the return values. You can have it return a null.

Comment: Thank you, I will check and hopefully work with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way for doing that is keeping another separate field for lastLogIn or logoff whatever.

Comment: But I still would need a way to update the LastLogIn field when the person logs in again OR create a new field if it's the person's first time.

Comment: How is your model?After your comment I am not sure if I correctly understand your question.

Comment: Right now the way I'm storing the data is by adding a new entry every time someone logs in or off, this is inefficient because old data is never used and just makes it harder to handle, so I want a way to update the last existing record (so I can keep the data I already have) or create a new one if the user hasn't logged in before (thus no record to update).